# In xterm, how do I bind Ctrl-minus but not Ctrl-Shift-minus?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xterm

My `.Xresources` looks like this:

```
! Change size with ctrl +-                                                                                            
XTerm.VT100.translations: #override \n\
  Ctrl <Key> minus: smaller-vt-font() \n\
  Ctrl <Key> plus: larger-vt-font()
UXTerm.VT100.translations: #override \n\
  Ctrl <Key> minus: smaller-vt-font() \n\
  Ctrl <Key> plus: larger-vt-font()
```

But this also binds Ctrl-Shift-Minus, (aka Ctrl-Underscore), which in Emacs (and Bash, and anything else Readline-based) means "Undo".

How do I make xterm not hijack Ctrl-Shift-Minus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `~Shift`:

```
  ~Shift Ctrl <Key> minus: smaller-vt-font() \n\
```

Comment: Thanks: Though specifically for plus I had to change to `~Shift Ctrl <key> equal`, which makes perfect sense. Thanks!